# How the controller can be customized in mininet

Tags: python, pox

How the controller can be customized in order to add rules in mininet software.

Comment: Take a look [here](http://mininet.org/blog/2013/06/03/automating-controller-startup/)

Answer (score 0):

There are variety of controllers. Some are interactive while dumb, meaning they can't control the network by them selves but they provide interactive interface to the uses to send open flow messages to the switch. An example of this would be iControl (This is for optical networks, yet it is a SDN controller).

Others may be smarter. For example, ONOS (http://onosproject.org/) is an operating system which tries to handle all the switches. You could for example, ask it perform as a hub or as a learning switch.

I have some tutorial on creating/working with controller on my github repo. This is for POX controller: https://github.com/Ehsan70/SDN

This is for iControl: https://github.com/Ehsan70/Mininet_LINC_script/blob/master/LINCoe_and_iControl.md

Also SDNhub is good resource: http://sdnhub.org/tutorials/pox/